# how to uplevel argument name(name2)?

Tags: tcl

I want to uplevel argument name kuku(pupu).
I tried to use the below but none of sthem succeeded.

`global kuku(pupu)`
`uplevel kuku(pupu)`
`upvar kuku(pupu)`

How can I up the var?

Comment: Just to confirm, by 'uplevel', you mean you want the variable to exist outside a `proc` that you have?

Comment: correct, most of the time I use global but it won't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to create the variable from inside the proc using global or uplevel. For global specifically, you cannot pass the variable name like that if it is an array, you can only pass the array name, like so if the upper namespace is global:

```
proc foo {} {
    global kuku
    set kuku(pupu) "some value"

    # anything else to do
    return
}

foo
puts $kuku(pupu)
```

You could use `uplevel` a bit differently like this:

```
proc foo {} {
    set kuku(pupu) "some value"
    uplevel [list set kuku(pupu) $kuku(pupu)]

    # anything else to do
    return
}

foo
puts $kuku(pupu)
```

Using `upvar` would be yet a bit different:

```
proc foo {arrayName} {
    upvar $arrayName newName
    set newName(pupu) "some value"

    # anything else to do
    return
}

foo kuku
puts $kuku(pupu)
```

IMO:

- using `global` is the simplest, but you need to remember it works on the array name only, for arrays
- For `uplevel`, you have to think about what should execute in the upper namespace (in this case, I wanted `set kuku(pupu) "some value"` to happen in the upper namespace) and can be a little difficult to grasp maybe.
- `upvar` creates an alias from a variable in an upper namespace and makes it accessible locally. The alias can have the same name, it's just a bit less confusing if you use a different name from the original. A little similar to `global`, it works on the array name only.

Comment: succeeded to set it with upvar but can't read it by another proc.
`puts yyy {} {                                                                                                                                                                                                   puts $kuku(pupu)                                                                                                                                                                                                  }`

Comment: `proc yyy {} {
puts $kuku(pupu)
}
`

Comment: @user3835935 you will have to make the variable accessible within that proc, using either `global` or `upvar` in the same way as it was made accessible to global.

Comment: `global kuku(pupu)` doesn't work, these is the source problem

Comment: @user3835935 You forgot about using the array name and not the array-key?